# How to remove one step from a three step ladder?

Tags: stairs, ladder

I bought a three step ladder for some alternative use. However, I need to remove the first bottom step, but don’t really know where to start. Is there a smart way to remove it, except for just cutting the wires that hold it?

Here are some visuals:
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it does not appear to be about home improvement.

Comment: Its about DIY and a way to improve my home, so I don’t understand your argument

Comment: You say "for some alternative use" in the post. If you explained what you intend to do, the community would embrace the question and perhaps give you some alternative ideas on how to accomplish your objective. Disassembling a ladder, in and of itself, does not relate to "home improvement".

Comment: Watch that first step; It's a doozie.

Comment: I understand your arguments, but then we disagree on the purpose of this channel. For me its all about DIY (as the url domain name implies) and for you about home improvement (name of channel). To be further discussed in the meta. As to answer the question on Alternative use. I am planning to use it as a trey for eating from the couch. So in order to have space for my legs, I need the first step removed. Its kinds improving my quality of living at home during the quarantine period.

Comment: I am Not taking sides. "the purpose of this channel"  is specifically laid out in the rules and not a matter of opinion. It takes more than 1 vote,  or one person, to close a question.    It is not difficult to word it in a more rule friendly way or add the pertinent info in your comments to the body of the question.  We want to embrace you and your question, meet us half way.

Comment: Understood & agreed. We have an agreement :)

Answer (score 1):

Note the slots cut in the holes at which the supporting rods attach. The rods have a matching tang. It seems likely that you can fold the ladder in such a manner to allow the tang on the rod to align with the slot on the step which should then allow the rod to slip out..

It may be necessary to remove the other step to accomplish this, or you may be able to remove the desired step straight away.

Detail is missing for the main support rod.

Comment: Yes, it looks like the main support rod is peened over, which means you will likely need to cut the main support rod.

Comment: The OP needs to be aware that the rod between the legs do offer some stability to the bottom of the ladder. When the step and rod are gone, the bottom of the legs can spread easier if they have to occasion.

Comment: Not only that, but the weight rating of that type of step stool may be incumbent upon the steps sharing the total weight bearing capability equally among each other. Remove one and you may compromise the rest. We don't know what your "alternative use" is though.

Comment: See my comment on question. I intend to use it as a trey for eating from the couch. Need to remove the first step to have space for my legs.